# Contact Sharing based on child object

Tags: trigger, sharing, contact, criteria-based-sharing

I have a number of `Contacts` in the system, and a child object, `Company Profile`, with a lookup to `Contact`.  This object has a picklist, "Area".

The idea is that each `Contact` should be shared with as many "groups" of users as there are different Areas for each `Contact`.  So if Contact X has 3 `Company Profiles` with Area 1, Area 2 and Area 3 it should be shared with users from these three areas.

I have been analyzing how best to do this, and have a potential solution, but it's a bit of a kludge.  I would like to know if there is a better approach since I am working with a clean slate here.  Note that `Accounts` aren't present in the system.

My potential approach:

- Set `Contact` Org-Wide Sharing to Private
- Add Users to different Public Groups, one for each `Area` in the
  picklist.
- Create a trigger to copy the values to a new field Text    Area(255)
  in the `Contact` Record.  E.g. Contact X would have
  Area1;Area2;Area3 from their Company Profiles.
- Create a `Contact` Sharing rule to check if this Text Area field
  CONTAINS Area1 and if so, share with the Area1 group.  Repeat for
  all Areas.

Potential issues:

- Although the number of Areas per Contact should be small, using a
  Text Area field (255) there could potentially be overflow.  I can't
  use Long Text Area (32000) because they can't be used in Contact
  Sharing Rules.
- This approach seems fairly difficult to maintain, and unintuitive for
  the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a User trigger create ContactShares when a User is added to a Group.

```
public static void shareContacts(Map<Id, Set<Id>> groupToContacts)
{
    List<ContactShare> contactShares = new List<ContactShare>();
    for (Id groupId : groupToContacts.keySet())
    {
        for (Id contactId : new List<Id> ( groupToContacts.get(groupId) ))
        {
            ContactShare contactShare = new ContactShare();
            contactShare.UserOrGroupId = groupId;
            contactShare.ContactId = contactId;
            contactShares.add(contactShare);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you will need some more logic to figure out when a User is added to a group, and also to make sure you are not creating multiple shares for the same Contact. It seems like this would be a good starting point for your most flexible solution though.

Comment: I think you're right that code is the way forward here